# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4078 collation is not recognized by older client drivers

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

What I'm trying to achieve is, connecting to a remote `mssql` database which I don't have alter privileges to change any schema structure of database or table or column. 
It throws this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4078 The statement failed because
>   column 'columnName' (ID=8) uses collation Persian_100_CI_AI, which
>   is not recognized by older client drivers. Try upgrading the client
>   operating system or applying a service update to the database client
>   software, or use a different collation. See SQL Server Books Online
>   for more information on changing collations. [4078] (severity 16)

As I said the database is on a remote machine, so changing collation is not an option.

My guess is, some packages are not in a suitable version. To acknowledge this, I've tested my code on another machine which is working well. So It proves that the problem is not about the code.

Extra information:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
PHP7.2
```

Comment: The error message is basically saying that the MSSQL Drivers on **your** PC are out of date when compared to the collation of the data on the server! Can you update you local drivers? So your PC drivers dont match the version of SQL Server on your server

Comment: @RiggsFolly What does it mean by driver? which driver should I update?

Comment: To access a MSSQL database via PHP (any version) you have to have some Microsoft drivers on your PC. These dont come by default with a PHP distribution, you have to install them seperately

Comment: [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Here is a "Starter for 10", [Look at the MS page about MSSQL access from Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I'm using dblib driver.

Comment: It does not matter, whatever version you are using is not compatible with the SQLServer you are trying to access

Comment: There are different drivers and extensions. Personally I would go for ODBC because it is natively supported by Microsoft plus it is compatible with the PDO extension.

Comment: Read the links that I and @DanFromGermany have provided for you

Comment: Ok, let me see.